# Data Table: Grouping based on intervals where first and last rows share column values

Tags: r, data.table

I presently have a data.table with columns of the variety below:

```
userid contentid sessionid           closetime
 polly   movies          1 2018-12-16 20:44:09
 polly   music           2 2018-07-13 08:06:35
 polly   movies          3 2018-12-13 12:01:21
 john    music           4 2018-11-07 10:43:40
 john    music           5 2019-01-20 11:35:10
```

I would like to add a new column, called "sessionsSinceLastAttempt", that identifies the closest prior row with the same 'userid' and 'contentid' values as the present row, and then inclusively counts the number of rows between them where the 'userid' is still the same.

An example of the desired output:

```
userid contentid sessionid           closetime sessionsSinceLastAttempt
 polly   movies          1 2018-12-16 20:44:09                        0
 polly    music          2 2018-07-13 08:06:35                        0
 polly    music          2 2018-07-13 08:06:35                        2
 polly   movies          3 2018-12-13 12:01:21                        4
  john    music          4 2018-11-07 10:43:40                        0
  john    music          5 2019-01-20 11:35:10                        2
```

Presently, I have tried:

```
data[, sessionsSinceLastAttempt := {
presentcontent = contentid
.SD[, .(sessionsSinceLastAttempt = .N), by = cumsum(contentid == presentcontent)]}, by = c("userid")]
```

However, the result simply takes the cumsum() of all rows prior without creating groups based on 'contentid'. Anybody know a fix? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve] including the expected result which can be used for creating and verifying answers. As currently described it is not fully clear to me what the expected result is.- Thank you.

Comment: Great point. Apologies. Hope the example brings some more clarity.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I am still struggling with your example. Shouldn't `closetime` be sorted for each `userid`? Is it intended that `sessionid` 2 is duplicated in the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to count all rows which belong to a particular `userid` between two subsequent occurrences of `userid`, `contentid`.

For this, we introduce a helper variable `rn` which numbers the rows of each `userid` consecutively. Then, we can group by `userid`, `contentid` and take the differences in `rn`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, rn := rowid(userid)][
  , userSessionsSinceLastAttempt := c(0, diff(rn) + 1), by = .(userid, contentid)][]
```

> ```
>    userid contentid sessionid           closetime rn userSessionsSinceLastAttempt
> 1:  polly    movies         1 2018-12-16 20:44:09  1                            0
> 2:  polly     music         2 2018-07-13 08:06:35  2                            0
> 3:  polly    movies         3 2018-12-13 12:01:21  3                            3
> 4:   john     music         4 2018-11-07 10:43:40  1                            0
> 5:   john     music         5 2019-01-20 11:35:10  2                            2
> ```

Note that `sessionid` and `closetime` are not used. The result solely depends on the order of `userid` and `contentid`.

#### Data

```
DF <- readr::read_table("
userid contentid sessionid           closetime
 polly   movies          1 2018-12-16 20:44:09
 polly   music           2 2018-07-13 08:06:35
 polly   movies          3 2018-12-13 12:01:21
 john    music           4 2018-11-07 10:43:40
 john    music           5 2019-01-20 11:35:10")
```